# Cannot debug a Python regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I am trying to debug the following Python regular expression

```
<meta name="Author" content=".*(?P<uid>([a-zA-Z]*))@abc\.com.*
```

And I used the following string as a sample:

```
<meta name="Author" content="qwerty(qwerty@abc.com)#comments=release candidate for AA 1.1">
```

Could you clarify why the following code does not find the group "uid":

```
regex = re.compile(r'<meta name="Author" content=".*(?P<uid>([a-zA-Z]*))@abc\.com')
a = '<meta name="Author" content="qwerty(qwerty@abc.com)#comments=release candidate for AA 1.1">'
q = regex.search(a)
if q:
    print(q.group('uid'))
```

I've even made a DFA and still cannot understand why the group was not found.

Comment: You are not matching the `(` Which value is expected in the group uid? See https://regex101.com/r/BYRMXD/1

Comment: Simply remove `.*` subpatterns, they match all text on a line before and after the string you need to extract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is this:

```
regex = re.compile(r'(?P<uid>([a-zA-Z]*))@abc\.com')
a = '<meta name="Author" content="qwerty(qwerty@abc.com)#comments=release candidate for AA 1.1">'
q = regex.search(a)
if q:
    print(q.group('uid'))
```

Returns: `qwerty`

(As @Błotosmętek explains, your solution was not working because of the *greediness* of `.*`)

Comment: Why does not re.findall solve the greediness of the ".*"?

Comment: See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). Empty matches are still matches. And `findall` just means it doesn't stop after finding a match. *Non-empty matches can now start just **after** a previous empty match*.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by greediness of the `.*` pattern. In `content=".*(?P<uid>([a-zA-Z]*))@abc\.com` everything up to `@abc` is matched by `.*` leaving a null string to be matched by your group. The solution by Peter Prescott above is sound, but if you insist on a longer regexp, use:

```
r'<meta name="Author" content=".*\((?P<uid>[a-zA-Z]*)@abc\.com'
```

so that `.*` stops matching at `(`.

Comment: I see, and the solution proposed by Peter Prescott is surely working. But why does not the re.findall find the group?

Comment: @GrigoriyVolkov - if it works, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)